# Stored Procedure Returning Duplicate Invalid Row

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

ALTER Procedure [dbo].[spGetQualityReport]
 (
  @providerKey INT          
 )

AS


-- declare @providerKey INT          

-- set @providerKey = 1;

--Get Database providerId first
DECLARE @realProvId INT;
SET @realProvId = (SELECT TOP(1) providerId from providerKeyTranslation where keyValue LIKE @providerKey)-- Nine to be replaced by datasource

DECLARE @ProviderName varchar(500);
SET @ProviderName = (SELECT name FROM provider WHERE id = @realProvId)

DECLARE @cmsId varchar(50);
SET @cmsId = (select top(1) KeyValue from ProviderKeyTranslation pkt where @realProvId = pkt.ProviderId)

DECLARE @ProviderType varchar(200);
SET @ProviderType = (select name from providertype where id = (select providertypeid from provider where id =@realProvId))

DECLARE @stateValue INT;
SET @stateValue = (SELECT TOP(1) KeyValue from providerKeyTranslation where ProviderId = @realProvId)

(
SELECT DISTINCT
(select d.Name + ' - ' + d.Description from DataSource d where pcmv.DataSourceId = d.Id) as [Source],
m.Id as [Measure Key],
m.Name AS MeasureName,
cmm.Ordering as [Measure Sort Order], --(SELECT DISTINCT ordering FROM dbo.fnGetProviderMeasureSortOrder(@realProvId,pcmv.CategoryId,pcmv.MeasureId)), --(select Ordering from Category_Measure_Map cmm where cmm.MeasureId = pcmv.MeasureId and cmm.CategoryId = pcmv.CategoryId) as [Measure Sort Order],
(select Name from DataSource_Locale ds where pcmv.ProviderId = @realProvId and pcmv.DataSourceId = ds.Id) as [Dates of Measures],
@stateValue AS [State Value],
m.UnitTypeId,
@realProvId AS [Provider Id], 
@ProviderName AS [Provider Name],
@ProviderType as [Provider Type],
@cmsId as [CMS ID],
Value AS [Value],
pcmv.ConditionId,
pcmv.Denominator,  
(select Name from Condition c where c.Id = pcmv.ConditionId) as [Condition],
(select TOP(1)rg.Name from Report r, ReportGrouping rg where r.ConditionId = pcmv.ConditionId AND r.ReportGroupingId = rg.Id) as [Condition Type],
(select Ordering from Report r where r.ConditionId = pcmv.ConditionId) as [Condition Sort Order],
case when (r.rating = 1) then '$'
when (r.rating = 2) then '$$'
when (r.rating = 3) then '$$$'
when (r.rating = 4) then '$$$$' end
AS Rating,
sig.Name AS Significance, 
f.Name AS FootNote,
pcmv.Deaths,
pcmv.ObsRate,
pcmv.ExpRate,
pcmv.LowCI,
pcmv.UpperCI
FROM Measure m
RIGHT JOIN
(
providerConditionMeasureValue pcmv   
INNER JOIN Provider p on p.Id = pcmv.ProviderId and p.Id = @realProvId
INNER JOIN dbo.Category_Measure_Map cmm ON cmm.MeasureId = pcmv.MeasureId AND cmm.CategoryId = pcmv.CategoryId AND pcmv.ProviderId = @realProvId
LEFT JOIN Rating r 
 on pcmv.Rating = r.Id
LEFT JOIN Footnote f 
 on pcmv.FootnoteId = f.Id 
LEFT JOIN Significance sig 
 on pcmv.SignificanceId = sig.Id  

) ON m.Id = pcmv.MeasureId
--CROSS JOIN dbo.DataSource AS d
where m.MeasureTypeId = 1  /*Quality Measure Type */
--Group BY m.Id, m.Name, m.UnitTypeId, pcmv.MeasureId, pcmv.DataSourceId, pcmv.CategoryId, pcmv.providerId, p.Name, Value,pcmv.ConditionId,r.rating, sig.Name, f.Name, pcmv.Deaths, pcmv.ObsRate, pcmv.ExpRate, pcmv.LowCI, pcmv.UpperCI, pcmv.Denominator
)
UNION
(
SELECT 
(select d.Name + ' - ' + d.Description from DataSource d where pmv.DataSourceId = d.Id) as [Source],
m.Id as [Measure Key],
m.Name AS MeasureName,
cmm.Ordering as [Measure Sort Order],--(select Ordering from Category_Measure_Map cmm where cmm.MeasureId = pmv.MeasureId and cmm.CategoryId = pmv.CategoryId) as [Measure Sort Order],
(select Name from DataSource_Locale ds where pmv.ProviderId = @realProvId and pmv.DataSourceId = ds.Id) as [Dates of Measures],
@stateValue AS [State Value],
m.UnitTypeId,
@realProvId AS [Provider Id], 
@ProviderName AS [Provider Name],
@ProviderType as [Provider Type],
@cmsId as [CMS ID],
Value AS [Value],  
null,
pmv.Denominator,
NULL,
null,
NULL,
case when (r.rating = 1) then '$'
when (r.rating = 2) then '$$'
when (r.rating = 3) then '$$$'
when (r.rating = 4) then '$$$$' end
AS Rating,
sig.Name AS Significance, 
f.Name AS FootNote,
pmv.Deaths,
pmv.ObsRate,
pmv.ExpRate,
pmv.LowCI,
pmv.UpperCI

FROM Measure m
RIGHT JOIN
(
providerMeasureValue pmv   
INNER JOIN Provider p on p.Id = pmv.ProviderId and p.Id = @realProvId
INNER JOIN dbo.Category_Measure_Map cmm ON cmm.MeasureId = pmv.MeasureId AND cmm.CategoryId = pmv.CategoryId AND pmv.ProviderId = @realProvId
LEFT JOIN Rating r 
 on pmv.Rating = r.Id
LEFT JOIN Footnote f 
 on pmv.FootnoteId = f.Id 
LEFT JOIN Significance sig 
 on pmv.SignificanceId = sig.Id  

) ON m.Id = pmv.MeasureId
--CROSS JOIN dbo.DataSource AS d
where m.MeasureTypeId = 1/*Quality Measure Type */
--Group BY m.Id, m.Name, pmv.MeasureId, pmv.DataSourceId, pmv.CategoryId, m.UnitTypeId, pmv.providerId, p.Name, Value,r.rating, sig.Name, f.Name,  pmv.Deaths, pmv.ObsRate, pmv.ExpRate,pmv.LowCI,pmv.UpperCI, pmv.Denominator
)
```

Working on a stored procedure and it keeps returning the multiple measure sort order even though there is only one mapping in the category measure table. Help!

Comment: That's too much SQL for us to digest, and some sample data or schema might be useful. Which exact bit are we looking at? Are your multiple rows coming from the top half of the union, or the bottom, or one from each?

Comment: the measure sort order column

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to break it down and build it back up carefully - one of your joins is creating an inadvertent many-to-one join - perhaps you've left out a condition in the join or one of your assumptions is not holding.